# How to get MouseOver trigger event alter child items

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouseover

I have a `MouseOver` event for a border.  Within that border (further down) I have a couple of Borders with `RotateTransform`s... How can I, within the top level `Border` hover event alter their transform? (i.e. change their rotation?)

```
<Border.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#f0f0f0" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

Further down the tree, but inside this border is

```
<Border Padding="3" Width="73" Height="57" Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" Color="#aa505050" />
    </Border.Effect>
    <Border.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform Angle="-2" />
    </Border.RenderTransform>
</Border>
```

Comment: You could try a DataTrigger in an Inside-Border-Style with FindAncestor or ElementName binding to get Outside-Border-MouseOver.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that lol, would you mind writing a bit of code for me to look at? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `ChangePropertyAction` with a `MouseOver` trigger with specified `TargetObject`'s? ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn195723.aspx

Comment: @LPL Managed to get this to work actually, if you want to put it as an answer and Ill accept - thanks

Comment: Thanks for your offer. I'm not at my desk to share an error free sample. Feel free to add your working code to my answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `DataTrigger` in an inner border `Style` with `FindAncestor` or `ElementName` binding to get the `IsMouseOver` of your outer border.

i.e.

```
<Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="3"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="6"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger >
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```